# rows overflow in a table

Tags: adobe, livecycle

I have a table printed in a flowed form that exceed the number of row in the page and goes in overflow in the subsequent page ; there is a way to count the number of rows present ONLY in the subsequent page and not in the entire table ?

Answer (score 0):

By using this "xfa.host.currentPage", you can get the current page the row/field is on. 
And then do the summation of the rows based on the page number.